# ¿Como hago que una imagen se mueva a la derecha?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, img

Tengo este contenido en un HTML:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un contenido gradiante responsivo que contiene dos imagenes (la X y la estrella).

El codigo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#004AB1, #5DADE2 ); width: 5%; height: 100px !important; margin: 20px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
<p>
    <img src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_estrellas_apoyo.png" alt="logo_Cultura" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; height: 70px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <img src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_imagotipo_X.png" alt="logo_Provident" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; height: 100px;">
</p></div>
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, el problema me surge al momento de hacer la pantalla mas pequeña.

- La altura se hace más grande.
- Las imagenes se ponen una encima de otra en diferentes renglones
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero lograr es lo siguiente:

- Que la altura no se modifique
- Que la imagen (la estrella) se vaya recorriendo a la derecha conforme la pantalla se vaya haciendo más pequeña de lo ancho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme por favor. Gracias

Comment: te iba recomendar el comando align pero viendolo mejor me quedo y observo porque me intrigó

Comment: ¿Cual seria ancho del `div` a partir del cual la image de la estrella deberia empezar a "ocultarse"?

Comment: Desde la primer alteración que se le haga al ancho del div la imagen debe empezar a recorrerse.

Comment: Imaginate una resolucion de pantalla de por ejemplo 1920px de ancho ¿hasta que punto se podría achicar antes de empezar a ocultar la imagen de las estrella? Imagino que para una resolución menor a `1024px` ya debería ocultarse... lo que necesito saber es el "punto de quiebre"

Comment: Si, definamos que el "punto de quiebre" es 1024px. 

P.D.: La función principal que busco es que se vaya recorriendo a la derecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La más "simple" es usar una `table`, así por ejemplo:

- Al `div` lo indicamos que cuando contenido no entre, se oculte (`overflow: hidden`)
- Agregamos una `table` la cual va a ocupar el 100% del ancho del `div` y como mínimo va a medir `1024px`. Esta tabla va a tener una fila con 2 celdas
- La celda de la izquierda va a tener la "X"
- La celda de la derecha va a tener la "estrella" alineada a la derecha

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004AB1, #5DADE2);
  height: 100px !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.header table {
  width: 100%;
  /* Punto de quiebre */
  min-width: 1024px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/blankstock/blankstock1902/blankstock190200727/125609735-eliminar-icono-quitar-letrero-s%C3%ADmbolo-cancelar-o-cerrar-elemento-de-dise%C3%B1o-de-calidad-icono-de-estil.jpg?fj=1" width="100" alt="logo_Cultura"></td>
      <td class="text-right"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/frizio/frizio1512/frizio151200007/49579125-%C3%A9toile-d-or-com%C3%A8te-symbole-de-no%C3%ABl.jpg?fj=1" width="900" height="81" alt="logo_Provident"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**PD:** Podemos reemplazar la `table` con una estructura `flexbox` o `grid layout`. Si te interesa, dejamelo saber en los comentarios.

---

#### Actualización

Usando [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Ejemplo:

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004AB1, #5DADE2);
  height: 100px !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  min-width: 1024px;
}

.cell1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.cell2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell1"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/blankstock/blankstock1902/blankstock190200727/125609735-eliminar-icono-quitar-letrero-s%C3%ADmbolo-cancelar-o-cerrar-elemento-de-dise%C3%B1o-de-calidad-icono-de-estil.jpg?fj=1" width="100" alt="logo_Cultura"></div>
    <div class="cell2 text-right"><img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/frizio/frizio1512/frizio151200007/49579125-%C3%A9toile-d-or-com%C3%A8te-symbole-de-no%C3%ABl.jpg?fj=1" width="900" height="81" alt="logo_Provident"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, he hecho unas modificaciones al codigo y se ve mejor de lo que tenia antes.

Y estaría genial que me mostraras la estructura de `flexbox` o de `grid layout`.

Comment: @AngelRios agregue un ejemplo usando grid layout. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

La solución es muy fácil pero...
Si estás usando **bootstrap4**, deja que *bootstrap4* haga todo el trabajo. Basta con conocer sus clases de *CSS* para declarar en *HTML*, y sin tocar CSS (salvo algunos ajustes fuera de éste).

Tu ajuste *CSS* solamente, en este caso, sería el fondo.

Lo que hice es que agregué una clase en la etiqueta `<img>` con el estilo propio de *bootstrap4* que es: `float-left` y `float-right`.

Pero en tu caso, estás usando *bootstrap4* y quedaría así:

```css
.container {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#004AB1, #5DADE2 ); 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100px !important; 
 margin: 20px; 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
 border-radius: 10px; 
 padding-left: 20px;
}

.container img {
 background-color: violet
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="alinear.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <div class="container"> 
   
  <img class="float-left" src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_estrellas_apoyo.png" alt="logo_Cultura" >

<img class="float-right" src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_imagotipo_X.png" alt="logo_Provident" >
 
  
 </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Pero si no se usa *bootstrap4*, modifique un poco de tu código para que quedara así:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#004AB1, #5DADE2 ); 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100px !important; 
 margin: 20px; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
 border-radius: 10px; 
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.container img {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: auto;
 background-color: red;
}

.container .float-left {
 float: left; 
 margin-left: 0;
 height: 70px; 
}

.container .float-right {
 float: right; 
 margin-right: 0;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
   
<img class="float-left" src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_estrellas_apoyo.png" alt="logo_Cultura" > 
<img class="float-right" src="/pluginfile.php/57641/mod_book/intro/EX_imagotipo_X.png" alt="logo_Provident" > 
  
  </div>
```

**Importante**.

1. La etiqueta `<img>` no es necesario insertar dentro de una etiqueta `<p>` (las etiquetas `p` son solamente para textos)
2. No es necesario agregar en una etiqueta los estilos *CSS* (es mejor crear un nuevo archivo `.css` y linkearlo desde *html*